# Is there a bibTeX style file that produces references in the following format?

Tags: bibtex, packages

I have only a specification by example for writing a paper. Is there a bibTeX style that reproduces the following output:

> Books
>
> Blevins, Juliette. 2004. Evolutionary Phonology. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.
>
> Journals
>
> Johnson, Kyle, Mark Baker and Ian Roberts. 1989. Passive arguments raised. Linguistic Inquiry 20: 219–251.
>
> Collections
>
> Webelhuth, Gert ed. 1995. Government and Binding Theory and the Minimalist Program: Principles and Parameters in Syntactic Theory. Oxford: Blackwell.
>
> Chapters in collective volumes
>
> Jucker, Andreas H. and Sara Smith. 1998. And people just you know like ‘wow’: Discourse markers as negotiating strategies. In Andreas H. Jucker and Yael Ziv eds. Discourse Markers: Descriptions and Theory. Amsterdam: John Benjamins, 171–201.

Features: Given names are spelled out and are in front of the name except for the first author, blocks are separated by full stops, Journals are gives as "Name Number:Pages".

I know I can make such a style myself, but I want to know about existing bibTeX styles for this kind of lay-out.

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing bib style that incorporates of all your formatting requirements. I assume that by "I know I can make such a style myself", you're alluding to the `makebst` utility of the `custom-bib` package. For sure, that's what I was going to recommend you pursue if nobody steps forward with a pointer to an existing bst file.